# CSP being applied despite no Content-Security-Policy header

Tags: browser, content-security-policy

I'm having trouble figuring out why CSP is being applied to a page, when inspection of the request/response shows no `Content-Security-Policy` header being sent (see screenshot).

The application is a Jenkins instance, serving some static HTML content generated by a job, and it's previously had the restrictions relaxed as described here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy. This fixed the original instances of the static content not showing because of the CSP restrictions. Now, however, it came back in a different place, and the original solution is ineffective (for obvious reasons, as there's no header to modify). Just in case, I've verified that the custom CSP value is still set inside Jenkins. The problem happens in all of Firefox 64, Chromium 71, and Chrome 55.

How can I figure out where the CSP originates? Have browsers started to apply it by default now? I thought the whole point of CSP was that it was opt-in and degraded to same-origin policy if absent.

**EDIT:** There's no `<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy">` in the source either.

[image: Developer tools console]

Comment: Does the document have a `<meta http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy>` element?

Comment: Not that I could see. I checked for it, but forgot to add that in the question. I'll update it.

Comment: If there’s no Content-Security-Policy response header and no meta element, then it’s most likely you have some extension installed — e.g., Privacy Badger — that’s affecting the behavior. Try testing in a different browser or testing with extensions disabled — e.g., in a Private/Incognito window or from a new user profile in your browser.

Comment: I've already tested it in four different browsers (three of which were named above) across two different machines. The problem was first reported internally by a user (a coworker) on a yet another machine and browser with no shared config of any sort. The configuration is maintained privately by every user, there's no shared IT policy or config being blasted out. It's not an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually: it turned out to be a caching thing, despite me disabling doing non-cached reloads, apparently I wasn't doing it hard enough. That was hiding the original request, which *did* indeed have a CSP header. After clicking enough things in DevTools and settings, I was able to get it to re-issue the original request and could see it in the request view to see what was being applied.